# How to explain the following behavior when is and == are used in one statement?

Tags: python

I tried to understand what's happening below but I can't...

```
get_val = lambda: print('abc') or 5
print(1 is None == get_val())  # It prints False
print((1 is None) == get_val())  # It prints 'abc' then False
print(1 is (None == get_val()))  # It prints 'abc' then False
```

Note that I noticed this by debugging something like
`if a is None == f() is None` which is clearly not good, but it's surprising to me that f() is not executed at all.

Thank you a lot...

Comment: The comparison will be shortcircuited, since `1 is None` is False already, there is no need to run the last expression, which is the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `is` and `==` operators are *comparison operators*. Therefore, they will be *chained* when you use them like the first `print` call.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent
> to `x < y and y <= z`, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
> cases z is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if `a, b, c, …, y, z` are expressions and `op1, op2, …, opN` are
> comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to
> `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is
> evaluated at most once.

So, `1 is None == get_val()` is equivalent to `(1 is None) and (None == get_val())` Since `1 is None` is false, due to short-circuiting, `(None == get_val()` is never executed, and `abc` is never printed.

And finally:

```
a is None == f() is None
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(a is None) and (None == f()) and (f() is None)
```

Since `a is None` is probably *false*, then `f()` will never get evaluated.
Note, though, when it is chained, as the doc's state, `f()` is only actually evaluated once.